# Software for network hardware asset management, quite big problem!

Tags: networking, hardware, network-management

Not an issue for a small network, but becomes a pain when it grows. How can I track what ever happens to my network's hardware (repairs, upgrades, whatever) if I don't want to dig into loads of Excel and Access files?

UPDATE: Looks like it's called inventory or asset management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for software called "inventory" or "asset" management. It's basically a database that's built for what you're talking about. An example [here](http://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/asset-inventory-management.html).

Comment: Thanks for introduction, and this one looks pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

You may just want to install some kind of trouble ticket system, like RT. It will help you keep track of problems.

If you are looking at managing configuration changes, look into [Rancid](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/)

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what network hardware you have and what you mean by 'whatever happens', but if you want to know about warnings/failings/etc. then you could use a vendor-specific solution like CiscoWorks for their kit or a vendor-gnostic solution like Nagios or Cacti. If you're looking for physical asset management then some of these will help but ultimately you may need some form of spreadsheet/database depending on environment size.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Not talking about monitoring or managing system logs. Just want to simply track whatever happened to my hardware, like when they're added, upgraded, replaced and so on. A bit bookkeeping you know.